# I want to replace new line with break and spaces before/After the text must be same present

Tags: asp.net

I want to replace new line with break and spaces before the text must be same.
For eg:

**Text:**

This is .net class with 100 students.

```
 They are able to perform well.

      They require certification for career improvement.
```

This is the above format i require with same indent.

I have regular expression i.e  lblQuestion.Text = lang.Replace("\n", "
");
but it is replacing only text to next line but it is missing the spaces and giving me output as

PRESENT OUTPUT:

This is .net class with 100 students.

They are able to perform well.

They require certification for career improvement.

REQUIRED OUTPUT:

This is .net class with 100 students.

```
 They are able to perform well.

      They require certification for career improvement.
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about what task are you trying to solve? Because it looks like you might get what you need just by using the <pre>...</pre> tag

Comment: actually i am getting data dynamically into the string. And this string contains with the proper indent. If string is not replaced with \n with <br > then data is generated side by side. So i am using replace('\n',<br>).... But by using this spaces before text are getting missed.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to also replace each of the starting spaces with no break spaces (`&nbsp;`), so browsers will not [collapse the whitespace](http://www-sul.stanford.edu/tools/tutorials/html2.0/whitespace.html) to a single one.

A simple alternative is to enclose the output in `<pre></pre>` elements (stands for pre-formatted).

Answer (score 0):

The `pre` tag can be used to display text is the way you want, and without having to replace line-breaks with `br` tags. However, you might need to style the `pre` tag's font, as the default font seems to be mono-space for some browsers.

Edit:

Assuming you're using Web Forms, to do this dynamically, define a Literal control in your aspx markup, as follows:

```
<pre style="font-family:arial">
<asp:Literal ID="litText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</pre>
```

Then in your code-behind, set the Literal's Text:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    litText.Text = @"This is .net class with 100 students.
    They are able to perform well.
        They require certification for career improvement.";
}
```

Comment: This data is generated dynamically... it will not be same all the time.. So we need to use replace function mandatory... Can help me by using replace function?